# SharedPreferences - Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a little doubt about the `SharedPreferences` in `Android`.

To delete a preference, we mainly have two options:

First:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = (Editor) getSharedPreferences(Constants.APP_DEFAULT_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
edit.putString(Constants.PREF_ACC, null);
edit.commit();
```

Second:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = (Editor) getSharedPreferences(Constants.APP_DEFAULT_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
edit.remove(Constants.PREF_ACC);
edit.commit();
```

In either case, fetching  `Constants.PREF_ACC` value from `SharedPreferences` will return `null`.

I was wondering which one should I prefer. Is there any memory related issues in either of them? What will the `System.gc` behavior be with them?

Comment: Are you fetching before adding the value in sharedPref ?

Comment: Assume, I have set the preference value, accessed it and then trying to remove it, because its no longer valid. We will try to access it again, if required.

Comment: then both options are good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically `remove` is better than `put(null)`, because it removes both the key and value (once committed) instead of mapping (and keeping) the key to a null value.

But judging by the [Android 5.1.1 implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java#SharedPreferencesImpl.EditorImpl), they are equivalent :

```
    ...
    String k = e.getKey();
    Object v = e.getValue();
    // "this" is the magic value for a removal mutation. In addition,
    // setting a value to "null" for a given key is specified to be
    // equivalent to calling remove on that key.
    if (v == this || v == null) {
        if (!mMap.containsKey(k)) {
            continue;
        }
        mMap.remove(k);
    } else {
    ...
```

That is also what one of the `putXXX` methods ([putStringSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29)) documentation says :

> Passing null for this argument is equivalent to calling remove(String)
>   with this key.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [remove](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#remove(java.lang.String)).

When we [putString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) or [remove](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#remove(java.lang.String)) nothing is done, it is just marked in the [Editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html) as TO BE DONE and gets done only when [commit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit()) is called
And when the commit is called all the remove calls are executed before the put calls. So it is better to use the remove calls to remove something from the Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html) of the interface `SharedPreferences.Editor` for `remove(String)` :

> Mark in the editor that a preference value should be removed, which
>   will be done in the actual preferences once commit() is called.
>
> Note that when committing back to the preferences, all removals are
>   done first, regardless of whether you called remove before or after
>   put methods on this editor.

… and for `putInt(int)` :

> Set an int value in the preferences editor, to be written back once
>   commit() or apply() are called.

… there seem to be only one striking difference: **`remove(String)` calls will be "done first, regardless of whether you called remove before or after put methods"**.

That said, I really doubt the actual order of execution won't matter much to average use-cases, so you could just choose either one of those methods and be completely fine.

***p.s.***, I'm still looking for the concrete class of `SharedPreferences.Editor` which might provide more clues about this. Will update as soon as I found one.